# Node.js app detecting running on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm writing a node.js app that I would like to be easily deployed on Azure as well as other platforms. How can I detect if I am running under Azure?

The environment does not seem to have any special variables. `process.env.port` contains the pipe such as `\\\\.\\pipe\\2f95e604-fc02-4365-acfc-010a26242d02` which is all I can think of so far.

Detailed environment data is available through the `azure` module, but I only want to pull that in if I am running on Azure.

Comment: are you looking to detect if you are running in an Azure Website, A cloud service or both?

Comment: I'm running in an Azure Website.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure but have you tried process.platform ?

Comment: That tells me I am running on NT.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I use this:

```
if ('WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION' in process.env) ...
```